# Do claws have any special effects?

Tags: ninja-village

Ninja claws seems to be completely outclassed by the double hook spear.  Is there any reason to equip them at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://adeptgamer.com/forum/pages/ninja-village-guide/) ninja claws don't have any special effects, so they are rather useless.